# lexical scoping in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm reading this book: http://eloquentjavascript.net/ which I think is brilliant.

However I'm having difficulty understanding the following function, where does the function add(number) get its argument from?

```
function makeAddFunction(amount) {
  function add(number) {
    return number + amount;
  }
  return add;
}

var addTwo = makeAddFunction(2);
var addFive = makeAddFunction(5);
show(addTwo(1) + addFive(1));  // gives 9
```

I thought the answer would be 7 to this `show(addTwo(1) + addFive(1));`

In `makeAddFunction(2)`, amount is 2, but what would number be? so number + 2...

NB: show function is pretty much echo in php.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**See JAAulde's answer for what `makeAddFunction`'s purpose is, which was really the main question, imo**

The answer to your second question is, you generate two functions. They look like this (basically):

```
var addTwo = function add(number) {
    return number + 2;
};

var addFive = function add(number) {
    return number + 5;
};
```

It should be obvious why you get:

`addTwo(1) + addFive(1)`

`(1 + 2)` + `(1 + 5)` = 9 now.

Comment: Ah, so in `addTwo(1)`, the 1 is an argument of the add function

Answer (score 5):

`makeAddFunction` returns a new function. The new function takes a param, `number`, and adds it to whatever was originally given to `makeAddFunction`.

```
var addTwo = makeAddFunction(2);
// addTwo is now a function which you can call with a numeric argument ('number')
// anything you pass to it will have two added to it

var five = addTwo( 3 );  // add two to three (makes five)
```

Answer (score 1):

What would number be? Number is an argument to the returned function. I think you're thinking about this too hard.

`makeAddFunction(5)` effectively returns a named reference to `function(number) { return number + 5; }`